# Unexpected text found in layout file: "android:background="#AA00FF">"

Tags: android-studio, background-color, android-constraintlayout

Can not update the background color and warning show like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a formatting issue, there's probably a hidden/invisible character somewhere in the white space. You can try to find this hidden character or just delete the whole contents of the file and write it again!